# Weak Interaction (leptons to boson)

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

I'm going through a practice exam and saw this question.

Q: Which ONE of the following is an allowed weak interaction process?

I eliminated the possible answers to the following two.

1. $e^+$ + $\nu_e$ -> $W^+$
2. $e^-$ + $\nu_e$ -> $W^-$

Apparently the first option is correct, but I do not see how I can discern between the two. How to tell?

Answer (score 2):

Conservation of electron Lepton number!

Notice that the W+ is a boson meaning that it has zero lepton number.
Thus on the left hand side you should have zero lepton number as well.

In 1. you have +1 electron lepton number (from the electron neutrino) and -1 electron lepton number (from the positron) so that in total you aslo have zero electron lepton number on the left hand side. This is in fact the right process.

In 2. you have +2 electron lepton number (+1 from the eletron and +1 from the electron neutrino) on the left hand side of the proccess and so this quantity is not conserved.

For each lepton familly, the respective electron/muon/tau lepton number must be conserved in the process.

Comment: Note that the "electron antineutrino" is usually written $\bar \nu_e$.

Comment: If in process 2. the electron neutrino were instead an electron anti-neutrino, denoted as rob pointed out in the comment above, the process would be correct as well.